# Snowflake cascade deletion - 4 layers

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

How to have 4 layers of data deleted in snowflake - parent, child, grandchild, greatgrandchild?

I have 4 tables where data is to be deleted when data is deleted in the parent table. As cascade delete is not there in snowflake, how can we achieve this in an automated process?

Comment: What is your table structure exactly?

Comment: So do you have several tables or one parent/child hierarchy? Maybe its just SQL

Comment: I have several tables which are related to each other. For example, customer - parent, order - child, complaint - child to order, complaint_action - child to complaint. This way there are a few more tables. So, the requirement is, when a customer is deleted , orders, complaints, complaint_action and anything related to the customer is deleted. Just as cascade delete

Answer (score 0):

I'd just use tasks and streams for this.  You'd delete from the parent with a stream over it, and then a task would use the information in the stream to apply to the child, and so on.  You could have the tasks checking for changes on the parent every minute or so.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/tasks-intro.html

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/streams.html

https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/Using-Streams-and-Tasks-inside-Snowflake